# matplotlib.pyplot.legend Generates different Legends if ran on a different machine

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, legend

I wrote a script to automate a line plot, and it works well on my machine when I run the script. But when someone else tries running the same script, the legend uses different colors.

[Correct Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SZREw.png)

[Incorrect Image (Wrong Legend)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4a5lg.png)

Here is the script:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(15, 9)) 
plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight') 
chart = sns.lineplot(x = pd.to_datetime(buyer_comp_trend['week']).dt.strftime('%m/%d'), y = buyer_comp_trend['Composite Score'], color = '#0000ff', linewidth=7.) 
chart = sns.lineplot(x = pd.to_datetime(buyer_comp_trend_ce['week']).dt.strftime('%m/%d'), y = buyer_comp_trend_ce['Composite Score'], color = '#99ccff', linewidth=3.) 
chart = sns.lineplot(x = pd.to_datetime(buyer_comp_trend_ea['week']).dt.strftime('%m/%d'), y = buyer_comp_trend_ea['Composite Score'], color = '#990099', linewidth=3.) 
chart = sns.lineplot(x = pd.to_datetime(buyer_comp_trend_ma['week']).dt.strftime('%m/%d'), y = buyer_comp_trend_ma['Composite Score'], color = '#1f1f1f', linewidth=3.) 
chart = sns.lineplot(x = pd.to_datetime(buyer_comp_trend_ms['week']).dt.strftime('%m/%d'), y = buyer_comp_trend_ms['Composite Score'], color = '#00b050', linewidth=3.) 
chart = sns.lineplot(x = pd.to_datetime(buyer_comp_trend_sc['week']).dt.strftime('%m/%d'), y = buyer_comp_trend_sc['Composite Score'], color = '#ff66cc', linewidth=3.) 
chart = sns.lineplot(x = pd.to_datetime(buyer_comp_trend_so['week']).dt.strftime('%m/%d'), y = buyer_comp_trend_so['Composite Score'], color = '#996633', linewidth=3.) 
chart = sns.lineplot(x = pd.to_datetime(buyer_comp_trend_we['week']).dt.strftime('%m/%d'), y = buyer_comp_trend_we['Composite Score'], color = '#ff8205', linewidth=3.) 
plt.plot(pd.to_datetime(buyer_comp_trend['week']).dt.strftime('%m/%d'), buyer_comp_trend['Target'], c = '#808080', ls = '--') 
chart.set(title = 'HRX Composite Score (Region scores by week)', ylabel='', xlabel="", facecolor = '#ffffff') 
x = range(0, len(pd.to_datetime(buyer_comp_trend['week']).dt.strftime('%m/%d'))) 
plt.ylim(920, 980) 
plt.legend(labels = ['National', 'CE', 'EA', 'MA', 'MS', 'SC', 'SO', 'WE', 'Target (939)'], ncol=9)
```

We've tried updating python to the same version and updating matplotlib to the same version, but the same script still produces different images on the different computers.

Comment: Are you running the same matplotlib and seaborn versions on both machines?

Comment: The recommended way is to add `label=` to each item you want in the legend. And then call `plt.legend()` without `labels=`. So, `sns.lineplot(..., label='National')` etc.. That way it also becomes easier if you need modifications, e.g. to add are remove one of the curves. Normally this should work also when working with different seaborn versions.  Writing code that only works with older versions can lead to other problems in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to figure it out.
The issue was with the seaborn library. For some reason, the newest version of seaborn (0.12.1) was somehow messing up the colors assigned to each group in the legend. After downgrading seaborn to version 0.11.2, the issue was resolved.

Command used to downgrade seaborn was:

```
pip install --force-reinstall -v "seaborn==0.11.2"
```